# Scrollbar issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have two scrollbars here, and I want to fix them; I tried many times, but I cannot.

I have a script and installed it on the [Hostinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostinger) server; when accessing my site, I see a long, green scroll bar. How can I fix it?

```css
/*  custom css
================================================== */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #29c7ac;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
/*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
   scrollbar-width: none;
}*/
.mb-80 {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.pt-80 {
    padding-top: 80px;
}

.top_header_area {
    padding-top: 150px;
}

.layout_5 {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
}

.on-scroll.bg_color {
    position: relative;
}
```

[image]

**CSS**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gIPsDhyvUPZ11RcStUEl_1B6G7lKUy5/view?usp=sharing